# Сортировка двумерного масива

Tags: массивы, сортировка, php

Есть двумерный массив полученный после распарсивания страницы

```
$reit[1][0]='text1';
$reit[1][1]='text2'; 
$reit[1][2]='text3'; 
$reit[1][3]='text4';

$reit[2][0]='7'; 
$reit[2][1]='1'; 
$reit[2][2]='1';
$reit[2][3]='2';
```

Задача отсортировать, массив по второму столбцу... пробовал через array_multisort ничего не получается...

В конце должно получится:

```
$reit[1][0]='text1';
$reit[1][1]='text4'; 
$reit[1][2]='text2'; 
$reit[1][3]='text1';

$reit[2][0]='7'; 
$reit[2][1]='2'; 
$reit[2][2]='1';
$reit[2][3]='1';
```

Comment: Что-то логика сортировки непонятна..

Comment: Photon, это пары "ключ - значение". И сортировка идет по второму массиву по убыванию. Хотя действительно, что до этого нужно догадаться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот код

```
array_multisort($reit[2],SORT_DESC,$reit[1]);
```

выводит вот ето.

```
array(2) { [1]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "text1" [1]=> string(5) "text4" [2]=> string(5) "text2" [3]=> string(5) "text3" } [2]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "7" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(1) "1" } }
```

вам так надо? потому как у вас в вопросе ошибочка походу  так как ненахожу элемента text3  в массиве $reit[1]

Answer (score 0):

Вроде то что вам нужно 
http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.krsort.php#55577